Find settings override names
I would like to use settings overrides for my organization's address, telephone etc.
In our civicrm.settings.php file I have the following but it doesn't set these settings:
// WORKING
$civicrm_setting['domain']['extensionsURL'] = '[cms.root]/sites/all/extensions/';

// NOT WORKING
$civicrm_setting['domain']['org_name'] = 'Green Party of Ontario';
$civicrm_setting['domain']['org_address_line1'] = 'PO Box 1132 Station F';
$civicrm_setting['domain']['org_address_line2'] = 'Toronto, ON M4Y 2T8';
$civicrm_setting['domain']['org_tel'] = '(416) 977-7476';
$civicrm_setting['domain']['org_fax'] = '(416) 977-5476';
$civicrm_setting['domain']['org_email'] = 'admin@gpo.ca';
$civicrm_setting['domain']['org_web'] = 'gpo.ca';

I have also searched in this directory to find if any settings for these exist, however, I didn't find anything: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/tree/master/settings
I currently have this working function which sets the settings in the civicrm_config hook:
// WORKS
function hook_civicrm_config(&$config) {
  \Civi::settings()->set('org_name', 'Green Party of Ontario');
  \Civi::settings()->set('org_address_line1', 'PO Box 1132 Station F');
  \Civi::settings()->set('org_address_line2', 'Toronto, ON M4Y 2T8');
  \Civi::settings()->set('org_tel', '(416) 977-7476');
  \Civi::settings()->set('org_fax', '(416) 977-5476');
  \Civi::settings()->set('org_email', 'admin@gpo.ca');
  \Civi::settings()->set('org_web', 'gpo.ca');
  \Civi::settings()->set('org_charitable_no', '');
}

It seems like it should be possible to have all these settings defined as settings overrides. Any help is appreciated :D

Is there a way to see all the settings in a CiviCRM instance?
Why is it possible to write the settings using settings()->set() but not overrides

